# Joomla view different menu item when premium member

Tags: joomla

So I am currently using the Gantry framework alongside Community Builder and Gantry has an icon you can place next to a menu item such as ("premium content") the icon could be a padlock which is what it currently is.

When clicking on it, it will tell the user to become a premium user to view it. How do I get it so when the person is a premium member that the padlock icon changes to an unlocked padlock?

The icon is already there but it's a case of changing it in the menu item by making a new menu item probably. Just not sure how you hide the first one to display the second version.

***This is what I get to choose, so I could pick public main menu or premium but not both so I am confused.***

[image]

Comment: You will need to find out where the icon is being displayed from, then write a database query to detect whether or not the user is a premium member, then then display the icon according to the result.

Comment: @Lodder, this is Joomla, surely there is an easier way :P

Comment: This is Gantry, easy is not an option in this case :D

Comment: You can do this in Joomla 1.6+ using the ACL and a Guest group, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Joomla 2.5+ and the built-in ACL to assign "Premium Users" to a specific set of Joomla groups then it's pretty easy, by creating two menu items with the same title but pointing to different content and having different access levels.

1. Create a menu item with the required name but access set to "Guest" (if you're [on 2.5 read this on Guest groups](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Access_Control_List_Tutorial#Allowing_Guest-Only_Access_to_Menu_Items_and_Modules)) point it to a page/pop-up with your upsell message.
2. Create the second menu item pointing to the premium content and set it's access to your access group for "Premium Users". This will give you the same apparent menu but two different states, like the download menu on one of our sites:
   [image: Guest and Registered Menu items]

Comment: On Gantry you can only display one menu. Posted an image in my question

Comment: Sorted it like you said. Thank you